# Mysql get latest row for status

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a log table with several statuses. It logs the position of physical objects in an external system. I want to get the latest rows for a status for each distinct physical object.

I need a list of typeids and their quantity for each status, minus the quantity of typeids that have an entry for another status that is later than the row with the status we are looking for.

e.g each status move is recorded but nothing else.

Here's the problem, I don't have a distinct ID for each physical object. I can only calculate how many there are from the state of the log table.

I've tried

```
    SELECT dl.id, dl.status
    FROM  `log` AS dl
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(  `date` ) , id
      FROM  `log` 
      GROUP BY id ORDER BY `date` DESC 
    ) AS dl2
    WHERE dl.id = dl2.id
```

but this would require a distinct type id to work.

My table has a primary key id, datetime, status, product type_id. There are four different statuses.

a product must pass through all statuses.

Example Data.

```
date       typeid status    id

2014-01-13 PF0180 shopfloor 71941
2014-01-13 ND0355 shopfloor 71940
2014-01-10 ND0355 machine   71938
2014-01-10 ND0355 machine   71937
2014-01-10 ND0282 machine   7193
```

when selected results for the status shopfloor I would want

```
quantity typeid
1        ND0355
1        PF0180
```

when selecting for status machine I would want

```
quantity typeid
1        ND0282
1        ND0355
```

The order of the statuses shouldn't matter it only matters if there is a later entry for the  product.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: Your model doesn't makes sense, please clarify. Is every product a distinct `id`, which would make it repeat over the rows? Is the `typeid` actually the product identification (each product has a distinct typeid)?

Comment: No. Typeid relates to a type of product, there are more than one of each product. There is no primary key relating to a product. (I didn't design this..)

Comment: What are the 4 statuses and what's their order?

Comment: from left to right: 'tray','machine','checkinbin','shopfloor' then the loop starts again.

Comment: Can you give an example where quantity = 2? I'm not sure where quantity is coming from. Would you need date, id, and typeid to be the same?

Comment: ORDER BY date in your subquery would serve no purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this will give you the desired output:

```
select
  l1.typeid, 
  l1.status, 
  count(1) - (
    select count(1)
    from log l2
    where l2.typeid = l1.typeid and
          l2.date > l1.date
  )
from log l1
group by l1.typeid, l1.status;
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2660c/15)

```
TYPEID  STATUS      TOTAL
-----------------------------
ND0282  machine     1
ND0355  machine     1
ND0355  shopfloor   1
PF0180  shopfloor   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the greatest date per `status`, not per `id`. Then join to the log table where the status *and* date are the same.

```
SELECT dl.id, dl.status
FROM  `log` AS dl
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT status, MAX(  `date` ) AS date
  FROM  `log` 
  GROUP BY status ORDER BY NULL
) AS dl2 USING (status, date);
```

It would be helpful to have an index on `(status, date)` on this table, which would allow the subquery to run as an index-only query.

Comment: There can be multiple dates and multiple types for each status so this wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Everton Agner originally posted this solution, but the reply seems to have disappeared so I'm adding it (with slight modifications)

```
select
  l1.typeid, 
  l1.status, 
  count(1) - (
    select count(1)
    from log l2
    where l2.typeid = l1.typeid and
          l2.`date` > l1.`date`
          AND l2.status != 'dieshop'
  ) as quant
from log l1
WHERE l1.status = 'dieshop' 
group by l1.typeid;
```

Comment: Oh does it work as you wish? I was thinking it may not work for some scenarios, so I've deleted the answer. I'm undeleting it then.